# Overridden Angular pipe is not used in sub-component

Tags: angular, overriding, angular-pipe

I'm overriding Angular's built-in `date` pipe to include better i18n for dates. I implemented the pipe in a "toolbox" project that is later included as a dependency in the main project. I wrapped the new pipe in a module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DateProxyPipe } from './dateproxy.pipe';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        DateProxyPipe
    ],
    exports: [
        DateProxyPipe
    ]
})
export class PipesModule { }
```

In the main project's `app.module.ts`, I import that module and set it in the providers:

```
import { PipesModule } from '../../../src/pipes/pipes.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GraphLegendComponent,
    TimeComponent,
    ...,
    DateProxyPipe
  ],
  providers: [
    DateProxyPipe,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This works beautifully when used directly, for example the `{{selectedTimespan.from | date:'medium'}}` in the template of the TimeComponent I left in the listing above is displayed in different formats when I change the language, exactly like I want it.

But it doesn't work in sub-components - i.e. the date pipe that is used in the template of a sub-component of the listed GraphLegendComponent does NOT change as the one in TimeComponent does.

I tried declaring, importing, providing etc. the DateProxyPipe in all sorts of locations, but can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
One of the sub-components is the TimespanShiftSelectorComponent. This is its module:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

...
import { TimespanShiftSelectorComponent } from './timespan-shift-selector/timespan-shift-selector.component';

const COMPONENTS = [
  ...,
  TimespanShiftSelectorComponent
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    COMPONENTS,
  ],
  exports: [
    COMPONENTS
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class TimeModule {
}
```

Comment: You are not importing `PipesModule`.

Comment: You should not redeclare `DateProxyPipe` in the main module, since it's already declared and exported from your `PipesModule`

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Thanks, that was one of the things I tried: adding `PipesModule` to `AppModule`'s `imports`. Then Angular complained about me declaring DateProxyPipe twice in PipesModule and AppModule, so I removed it from the `declarations` of the latter (which is what @David suggested anyway). Sadly, that doesn't fix it, behaviour is as before. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you show your module declaration for your sub component?

Comment: I updated the question with one of the sub-component's module

Comment: Did you try to import the PipesModule on AppsModule and remove all reference of DateProxyPipe in AppsModule (just the module import of PipesModule) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple actually, the problem is that you don't import the `PipesModule` into all your modules. Just importing it to `AppModule` doesn't allow feature modules to gain access to the content of `PipesModule`.

I would recommend creating a `SharedModule` where you import and export `PipesModule` as well as anything else that you need to share (excluding component modules as it will create circular dependency).

For components create another `ComponentModule` and import and export your component modules.

Now in your feature modules simply import `SharedModule` and `ComponentsModule` and you will have access to everything, everywhere.

This is an example of a `SharedModule` which I'm using:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,

    // 3rd party
    DirectivesModule,
    LoadingBarHttpClientModule,
    PipesModule,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,

    // 3rd party
    DirectivesModule,
    LoadingBarHttpClientModule,
    PipesModule,
    TranslateModule
  ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

And a `ComponentsModule`:

```
import {COMPONENTS} from '../components/components';
import {COMPONENTS_PROVIDERS} from '../components/providers';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    COMPONENTS
  ],
  exports: [
    COMPONENTS
  ]
})

export class ComponentsModule {

  public static forRoot() {

    return {
      ngModule: ComponentsModule,
      providers: COMPONENTS_PROVIDERS
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought importing the pipe into the top-most module would make it available everywhere. Thanks for pointing out this mistake.